# jGit clone remote git respository from Java

Tags: java, git, github, git-clone, jgit

I am using the below java code to clone a git repo.

```
localRepo = new FileRepository("/Users/myfolder/git" + "/.git");
            git = new Git(localRepo);
                   Git.cloneRepository().setURI("git@github.com:mygit/TestGit.git")
                    .setDirectory(new File("/Users/myfolder/git")).call();
```

I can see the project cloned in the folder /Users/myfolder/git, but in the console log I see the exception

```
fatal: Could not switch to
```

Any idea why the exception is being thrown even though everything works fine?

Answer (score 0):

That error comes from git itself in [`abspath.c#real_path_internal()`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/77bd3ea9f54f1584147b594abc04c26ca516d987/abspath.c#L84-L90), which returns the real path (i.e., absolute path, with symlinks resolved and extra slashes removed) equivalent to the specified path.

Make sure you are using an absolute path, and try using `/Users/myfolder/git` (without `.git`), as [in this cookbook example](https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/blob/master/src/main/java/org/dstadler/jgit/porcelain/CloneRemoteRepository.java).

Comment: i tried changing to  localRepo = new FileRepository("/Users/myfolder/git"); Still the same error.

Comment: @Upen is there a .git folder within "`/Users/myfolder/git`"? Is this folder a git repo? Are you on Windows or Linux or Mac? (`/Users` made me think of windows, but it could be Mac)

Comment: I am on mac. Everything time I run the program the "git" folder gets created.

Comment: under "git", the project gets cloned and .git folder is created

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to git Git result = Git.cloneRepository().setURI(REMOTE_URL).setDirectory(localPath).call()